# Web API always can't connect to MYSQL db after using some days later

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-web-api

I have a `Web API`, it's not working which cant connect to that `MYSQL` server after it working for about 20 days,for it go back to fine I have to restart the server ,thats really bizarre, I tried to connect to that `MYSQL` server with else toolkit like navicat something during the time that it cant connect to that database, it's NOT working as well,it just can't connect to MySQL databases showing the state code like `S1000` or like `10055`(I tried to google that code, it doesn't work,I have no idea how to deal with that issue)
my Web API built in C# on VS 2015 with EF 5.0, .NET 4.6. I deployed it on a Windows 2008 R2 server, there are 3 web api on the IIS on this web server, and there's else server which is a Windows 2008 R2 as well, it has MySQL server which version is 5.5, due to I'm just developer, I just log the exception in the web server level,I tried to find the log files on the MySQL side, the DBA didn't log any file on that database which was really unfortunate.

Here is my code which is the controller

```
  public DMLjfretModels uploadjfdetails(DMLjfparamsModels dmlparms)
    {
        DMLjfretModels dmlret = new Models.DMLjfretModels();
        dmlret.returncode = 0;
        dmlret.expmsg = "";



        if (dmlparms.clicardjftype != "1" && dmlparms.clicardjftype != "2" && dmlparms.clicardjftype != "4")
        {
            dmlret.returncode = -30;
            return dmlret;
        }

        if ((dmlparms.clicard??"").Trim().Length != 10)
        {
            dmlret.returncode = -60;
            dmlret.expmsg = "cardno is invald";
            return dmlret;
        }

        try
        {
            using (var context = new testEntities())
            {
                context.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    Globalvariable glv = new Globalvariable();
                    int result = glv.validate(dmlparms.username, dmlparms.password, dmlparms.curno);
                    if (result!=0)
                    {
                        dmlret.returncode = result;
                        return dmlret;
                    }

                    string clicardstring = dmlparms.clicard.Trim();
                    var memberresult = context.wp_client_card.Where(x => x.cli_card == clicardstring);
                    int therecordscount = memberresult.Count();

                    try
                    {
                        string filePath = @"d:\\log\\lognumber" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".txt"; 

                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("cli_card:" + clicardstring ?? "" + ",listno:" + dmlparms.clicardjflistno ?? "" + ",countvalue:" + therecordscount.ToString());
                            writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string filePath = @"d:\\log\\Error" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".txt";

                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("Message :" + ex.Message + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine + "StackTrace :" + ex.StackTrace +
                               "" + Environment.NewLine + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                            writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                    }

                    if (therecordscount == 0)
                    {
                        dmlret.returncode = -25;
                        return dmlret;
                    }



                    if (dmlparms.clicardjftype== "1" || dmlparms.clicardjftype == "2")
                    {
                        foreach (DMLdetailModels dm in dmlparms.clidetails)
                        {
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dm.prodno) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(dm.batchno)
                                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(dm.prodadd) || dm.prodnum <= 0.0 || dm.sellprice <= 0.0
                                || dm.stdprice <= 0.0  || dm.clicardjfnum<=0.0)
                            {
                                dmlret.returncode = -33;
                                return dmlret;
                            }
                        }
            
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        decimal thesum = context.wp_cli_card_jf.Where(x => x.cli_card==dmlparms.clicard.Trim()) 
                         .Sum( 
                                        d =>
                                        ((d.cli_card_jf_type == "1") && (d.cli_card_jf_num != null))
                                         ? d.cli_card_jf_num
                                          : ((d.cli_card_jf_type == "2") && (d.cli_card_jf_num != null))
                                          ? ((Decimal?)((Decimal)0) - d.cli_card_jf_num)
                                          : ((d.cli_card_jf_type == "4") && (d.cli_card_jf_num != null))
                                          ? ((Decimal?)((Decimal)0) - d.cli_card_jf_num)
                                          : (Decimal?)((Decimal)0)
                                           )??0.0M;

                        

                        decimal thesumjf = 0.0M;
                        foreach(DMLdetailModels details in dmlparms.clidetails)
                        {
                            thesumjf = thesumjf + Convert.ToDecimal( details.clicardjfnum);
                        }

                        if (thesum< thesumjf)
                        {
                            dmlret.returncode = -50;
                            return dmlret;
                        }

                    }

                    foreach (DMLdetailModels detail in dmlparms.clidetails)
                    {
                        //write the data into my database
                        context.wp_cli_card_jf.Add(wjf);
                    }

                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return dmlret;

                }
                else
                {   
                    dmlret.returncode = -20;
                    return dmlret;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           
           logfile(ex);
        }

    }
```

btw I have log the request and response as well within the webapi

```
      public class LogRequestAndResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        String UUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        // log request body
        string requestBody = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        string requestmethod = request.RequestUri.ToString();
        string mymethod = requestmethod.ToLower();



        // let other handlers process the request
        var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (result.Content != null)
        {
            // once response body is ready, log it
            var responseBody = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            logrequestnresponse(UUID, requestBody, responseBody.ToString(), mymethod);
        }

        return result;
    }


    private void logrequestnresponse(string uuid, string requestbody, string responsebody,string requestmethod)
    {
        try
        {
             using (var context = new testEntities())
              {
                  context.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;
                  wp_web_api_log wplog = context.wp_web_api_log.Create();
                  wplog.row_index = uuid;
                  wplog.request_detail = requestbody;
                  wplog.request_url = requestmethod;
                  wplog.response_detail = responsebody;
                  context.wp_web_api_log.Add(wplog);
                  context.SaveChanges();
              } 

            string filePath = @"d:\\log\\Logfile.txt";

      
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
             logfile(ex);

         }
    }
}
```

my log file logged that it cant connect to MYSQL database during that time

```
 Message :The underlying provider failed on Open<br/>
 StackTrace :   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
 at dggyapi.LogRequestAndResponseHandler.Logrequestnresponse(String uuid, String requestbody, String responsebody, String requestmethod),"},method:querymember
 Overall Exception:System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on           Open---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalBind(EndPoint localEP)
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
 at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.CreateSocketStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, IPAddress ip, Boolean unix)
 at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.CreateStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, Boolean unix)
 at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
 ---  End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
 ---  End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
 at dggyapi.LogRequestAndResponseHandler.Logrequestnresponse(String uuid, String requestbody, String responsebody, String requestmethod)
 Innerexception:System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalBind(EndPoint localEP)
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
 at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.CreateSocketStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, IPAddress ip, Boolean unix)
 at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.CreateStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, Boolean unix)
 at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
```

I just restarted my web server ,and tried to tracking the persistences and i found

```
  mysql> show status where variable_name like 'thread%';
  +-------------------+-------+
  | Variable_name     | Value |
  +-------------------+-------+
  | Threads_cached    | 4     |
  | Threads_connected | 41    |
  | Threads_created   | 53302 |
  | Threads_running   | 2     |
  +-------------------+-------+
  4 rows in set

  mysql> show processlist;
    +----------+---------+--------------------+--------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
  | Id       | User    | Host               | db     | Command | Time | State | Info             |
        +----------+---------+--------------------+--------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
  |  3540670 | myuser  | localhost:56924    | NULL   | Sleep   |  111 |       | NULL             |
  |  3540671 | myuser  | localhost:56925    | NULL   | Sleep   |  111 |       | NULL             |
  |  3540692 | myuser  | localhost:56928    | NULL   | Sleep   |    2 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278418 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1038 | mydb   | Sleep   |   44 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278428 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1043 | mydb   | Sleep   |   38 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278439 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1044 | mydb   | Sleep   |   33 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278441 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1045 | mydb   | Sleep   |   15 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278597 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1077 | mydb   | Sleep   |   18 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278602 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1078 | mydb   | Sleep   |    6 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278627 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1080 | mydb   | Sleep   |  102 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278654 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1082 | mydb   | Sleep   |  102 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278668 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1087 | mydb   | Sleep   |   97 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278710 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1088 | mydb   | Sleep   |   89 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278768 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1089 | mydb   | Sleep   |   89 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278780 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1090 | mydb   | Sleep   |   88 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278781 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1091 | mydb   | Sleep   |   85 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278805 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1092 | mydb   | Sleep   |   76 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278860 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1093 | mydb   | Sleep   |   73 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278877 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1094 | mydb   | Sleep   |   66 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278898 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1099 | mydb   | Sleep   |   54 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278913 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1100 | mydb   | Sleep   |   46 |       | NULL             |
  | 11278935 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1101 | mydb   | Sleep   |   42 |       | NULL             |
  | 11303229 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:1833 | mydb   | Sleep   |    3 |       | NULL             |
  | 11307621 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:2006 | mydb   | Sleep   |  161 |       | NULL             |
  | 11307953 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:2028 | mydb   | Sleep   |   93 |       | NULL             |
  | 11307998 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:2029 | mydb   | Sleep   |   76 |       | NULL             |
  | 11308004 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:2030 | mydb   | Sleep   |   74 |       | NULL             |
  | 11308244 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:2038 | mydb   | Sleep   |  147 |       | NULL             |
  | 11308349 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:2044 | mydb   | Sleep   |  132 |       | NULL             |
  | 11308350 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:2045 | mydb   | Sleep   |  127 |       | NULL             |
  | 11308387 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:2051 | mydb   | Sleep   |  126 |       | NULL             |
  | 11308416 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:2052 | mydb   | Sleep   |  119 |       | NULL             |
  | 11308454 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:2053 | mydb   | Sleep   |   71 |       | NULL             |
  | 11308460 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:2054 | mydb   | Sleep   |   98 |       | NULL             |
  | 11308487 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:2055 | mydb   | Sleep   |   44 |       | NULL             |
  | 11308498 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:2056 | mydb   | Sleep   |   23 |       | NULL             |
  | 11308542 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:2057 | mydb   | Sleep   |   13 |       | NULL             |
  | 11308560 | myuser  | 192.168.0.200:2058 | mydb   | Sleep   |   10 |       | NULL             |
  | 11308682 | myuser  | server5:5190       | NULL   | Sleep   |  117 |       | NULL             |
  | 11308722 | myuser  | server5:51903      | mydb   | Query   |    0 | NULL  |       show processlist |
        +----------+---------+--------------------+--------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
  40 rows in set
```

was that normal?

Comment: sorry for getting back you late,thank you so much sir @LeandroBardelli really apperciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be clear, the error says:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.
```

Causes of this can be multiple (you can google it) but usually is because lack of hardware, lack of server update, obsolete update, or you don't dispose the objects on the connection, or don't close connections, lack of memory, insufficient resources, but in definition: you are using a lot of ports.

You can try this:

On Windows Server 2008 R2
Open command Prompt

Type the following
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=10000 num=50000
Press Enter

Type the following
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport udp start=10000 num=50000
Press Enter

Type the following
netsh int ipv6 set dynamicport tcp start=10000 num=50000
Press Enter

Type the following
netsh int ipv6 set dynamicport udp start=10000 num=50000
Press Enter

More info at:
http://web.archive.org/web/20160118151510/http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/10/29/port-exhaustion-and-you-or-why-the-netstat-tool-is-your-friend.aspx

https://blog.whitesites.com/blog.aspx?key=635140180116307813

Comment: honestly, I didnt tried to execute those commands coz it was a urgent scene which I had to restart the server ,even the problem was gone temporary and the problem didnt really fixed yet,but I gonna try to reduce the ports within my code,I really appericate your helps,hopefully it gonna fix my problem